# How to update values to 1 or 0 into database with checkboxes javascript/php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Ok so I changed my code, what I'm trying to do is list users in a table and have a toggle-swtich button (checkbox with css) for each user when I press the button it will change the state of the user in my database 1 or 0 depending on the value of the checkbox. Using 2 buttons would be easier at this point, but I want to use the same button. I already have the table and I'm  showing the users, and the state just for testing, the checkbox doesnt seem to stay checked when clicked and I would like to know how to use the values of the checkbox so I can insert that into the database (yes I have to  change my query).

UPDATE.PHP

```
//update.php

include('database_connection.php');

$message = '';

$form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$query = "UPDATE tbl_user SET state=1 WHERE id = '".$form_data->id."'";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
if($statement->execute())
{
 $message = 'User updated';
}

$output = array(
 'message' => $message
);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

INDEX.PHP

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>Prueba</title>  
        <link href="StyleCheckBox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>  
    </head>  
    <body>  


        <div class="container">  
   <br />
            <h3 align="center">Prueba</h3><br />
   <div class="table-responsive" ng-app="liveApp" ng-controller="liveController" ng-init="fetchData()">
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" ng-show="success" >
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" ng-click="closeMsg()" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                    {{successMessage}}
                </div>
                <form name="testform" ng-submit="insertData()">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>State</th>
                                <th>Item</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" ng-model="addData.first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter state" ng-required="true" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" ng-model="addData.last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter user" ng-required="true" /></td>
                                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-disabled="testform.$invalid">Add</button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="data in namesData" ng-include="getTemplate(data)">
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
                <script type="text/ng-template" id="display">

                    <td>{{data.first_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.last_name}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-switch" ng-click="deleteData(data.id)">
                    </td>
                </script>

   </div>  
  </div>
    </body>  
</html>  
<script>
var app = angular.module('liveApp', []);

app.controller('liveController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.addData = {};
    $scope.success = false;

    $scope.getTemplate = function(data){
        if (data.id === $scope.formData.id)
        {
            return 'edit';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'display';
        }
    };

    $scope.fetchData = function(){
        $http.get('select.php').success(function(data){
            $scope.namesData = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.insertData = function(){
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:"insert.php",
            data:$scope.addData,
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.success = true;
            $scope.successMessage = data.message;
            $scope.fetchData();
            $scope.addData = {};
        });
    };

    $scope.reset = function(){
        $scope.formData = {};
    };

    $scope.closeMsg = function(){
        $scope.success = false;
    };

    $scope.deleteData = function(id){

            $http({
                method:"POST",
                url:"delete.php",
                data:{'id':id}
            }).success(function(data){
                $scope.success = true;
                $scope.successMessage = data.message;
                $scope.fetchData();
            }); 

    };

});

</script>
```

Comment: And what doesn't work with this code? Do you get an error?

Comment: I think the problem is that you update your database after showing the checkboxes. You need to update your database before you querying it for the User-status

Comment: It updates all users with the last checkbox value, for example if I check the last box all users will be updated to 1 and viceversa. It seems to ignore the other checbox values so it doesn´t update independently @MickaelLeger

Comment: One of the problem I think is your input name : you do a while loop and each checkbox have the same name, so if you have 10 user you will have 10 checkbox with `NAME="estado"`, it will be a problem. You need to have one unique name by input so you can select each one

Comment: Ok so what you should change : 1/ Add your `$select` in the HTML part (after `<body>` and before `<input...>`. 2/ Create ONE unique name by input (add the user_id for example for each). 3/ On submit, you need to get ALL input data and foreach do a prepare statement that looks like `$query3 = "UPDATE administrador SET estado=$estadoAdmin WHERE id_user = :id_user";` so you will update each user with the right value according to the checkbox of each user

Comment: Ok so I made the changes, but where do I place the id_user on each `<input...>`  to identify it? will I need to `$_POST[id_user]`  to get the id that will be used on the query? or should `...WHERE id_user = :id_user";` work just like that? I also thought of `...WHERE id_user = ?";` . Sorry still learning... @MickaelLeger

Comment: You can name your input using the id_user, so it looks like `name = 'estado_XXX'` with XXX the user_id, this way you know the id_user is after the `_` for each input that will be in your `$_POST` data

Comment: any ideas with de update?@MickaelLeger